# NoClassDefFoundError in Android while using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with the Google Maps to use Maps for my application.I am facing issues in the `getDeviceLocation()` method.

> My code is as follows :

```
package com.example.anvay.googlelocation;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

/**
 * Created by User on 10/2/2017.
 */

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {



    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getLocationPermission();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
            **getDeviceLocation();**
        }

    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            **Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);**

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I am getting error in Android Studio as follows :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
at com.example.anvay.googlelocation.MapActivity.getDeviceLocation(MapActivity.java:82)
        at com.example.anvay.googlelocation.MapActivity.onMapReady(MapActivity.java:60)
```

Comment: Why do you have this `**getDeviceLocation();**` enclosed in asterisks??

Comment: it was that line indicating error in android studio